# How to correctly use strftime and datetime using Room library?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I have an entity `Memo` class. I use `@TypeConverter` to convert `GregorianCalendar` to `Long`.

Memo.java

```
@Entity
public class Memo {
    @Ignore
    public static final int TYPE_EXPENSE = 0;
    @Ignore
    public static final int TYPE_INCOME = 1;

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    public int type;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_name")
    public String itemName;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_name")
    public String categoryName;
    public String note;
    public double dollar;
    public GregorianCalendar date;
    public String photoPath;

    @Ignore
    public Memo(int type) {
        this.type = type;
        itemName = "";
        categoryName = "";
        note = "";
        dollar = 0d;
        date = new GregorianCalendar();
        photoPath = "";
    }

    public Memo() {
        this(TYPE_EXPENSE);
    }

    @Ignore
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("id = " + id);
        builder.append(", itemName = " + itemName);
        builder.append(", type = " + type);
        builder.append(", categoryName = " + categoryName);
        builder.append(", note = " + note);
        builder.append(", date = " + date.getTimeInMillis());
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Converters.java

```
public class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    public static GregorianCalendar fromTimestamp(Long value) {
        if (value == null)
            return new GregorianCalendar();
        else {
            GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(value);
            return calendar;
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long millisToTimestamp(GregorianCalendar calendar) {
        return calendar == null ? null : calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }
}
```

I want to get the first and the last record in the database and get the `MemosWithTimestamp` object as a result.

```
public class MemoWithTimestamp {
    public int year;
    public int month;
    @Embedded
    public Memo memo;

    @Ignore
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("year=" + year);
        builder.append(", month=" + month);
        builder.append(", memo=[ "+memo.toString()+"]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Query methods:

```
    @Query("SELECT *, CAST(strftime('%Y', datetime(date)) AS int) AS year, CAST(strftime('%m', datetime(date)) AS int) AS month FROM memo ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1")
    MemoWithTimestamp getTheLastMemo();

    @Query("SELECT *, CAST(strftime('%Y', datetime(date)) AS int) AS year, CAST(strftime('%m', datetime(date)) AS int) AS month FROM memo ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1")
    MemoWithTimestamp getTheFirstMemo();
```

Data in the database in the Logcat:

```
id = 1, itemName = memo-2015-1-0, type = 0, categoryName = , note = , date = 1422634536401 <=first
....
id = 197, itemName = memo-2017-12-9, type = 0, categoryName = , note = , date = 1515428136414 <=last
```

Results after the query in the Logcat:

```
firstMemo= year=0, month=0, memo=[ id = 1, itemName = memo-2015-1-0, type = 0, categoryName = , note = , date = 1422634536401]

lastMemo= year=0, month=0, memo=[ id = 197, itemName = memo-2017-12-9, type = 0, categoryName = , note = , date = 1515428136414]
```

But the year and month fields always get 0 with or without `CAST`.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You miss 2 things here :

1) `datetime()` function gets seconds and you are passing milliseconds. Divide value by 1000.

2) You should pass second parameter as 'unixepoch' to `datetime()` function.

So, your query is fixed like this :

```
CAST(strftime('%Y', datetime(date/1000, 'unixepoch')) AS int) AS year
```

And same for month:

```
CAST(strftime('%m', datetime(date/1000, 'unixepoch')) AS int) AS month
```

Comment: I changed the query but it returns `lastMemo= year=2018, month=1, memo=[ id = 197, itemName = memo-2017-12-9, type = 0, categoryName = , note = , date = 1515428136414]`.

Comment: Another question: Is `CAST` really needed? Does the system alreadt convert the String value (`strftime` function) to Int?

Comment: Everything is correct, you have : `date = 1515428136414` , it is  **January 8, 2018** (`year=2018, month=1`), so your year and month from query are correct. `itemName` is different maybe because it was updated (it is string).  But extracting year and month from your date field (timestamp) is correct in my answer.

Concerning 2nd question, you don't need to CAST to int because %Y gives you `string` number and it will be correctly converted. But  the function normally gives you string, e.g. strftime(%Y-%m) would give you `'2018-01'`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I forgot to add 1 to month in the itemName.

Comment: just a quick note. if you compare the returning value of `STRFTIME`  to `int`, `CAST` will be necessary