# Room Database functions WEEK(), MONTH(), etc

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have a room database with a table "Entries" where I have the columns `value(int)`, `cat_id(int)` and `date(Date)`.

I want to get the sum of all entries of the current month and all entries of the current week. But the selections:

```
@Query("SELECT sum(value) FROM Entry WHERE cat_id = :cat_id AND WEEK(date, 5) = WEEK(:date, 5) AND YEAR(date) == YEAR(:date)")
float getValueThisWeekByCatId(int cat_id, Date date);

@Query("SELECT sum(value) FROM Entry WHERE cat_id = :cat_id AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(:date) AND YEAR(date) == YEAR(:date)")
float getValueThisMonthByCatId(int cat_id, Date date);
```

don't work.

This is the error:

> There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing
>   database (no such function: WEEK)
>       float getValueThisWeekByCatId(int cat_id, Date date); Same with function MONTH

Is there another way to that selection?

Comment: Sqlite date and time functions (and the timestamp formats they accept): https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html You probably want `strftime()`.

Comment: @Shawn `strftime()` works, but it sums up every entry, not only the ones I want. For example, on entry has the date '2019-03-19' and the value '50' and one entry has the date '2019-02-20' and the value '30'. My query looks like that: `Query("SELECT sum(value) FROM Entry WHERE cat_id = :cat_id AND strftime('%m', date) = strftime('%m', CURRENT_DATE) AND strftime('%Y', date) = strftime('%Y', CURRENT_DATE)")
    float getValueThisMonthByCatId(int cat_id);`
  It should be 50, but it's 80.

Comment: Check this for android room database https://stackoverflow.com/a/48135885/7710739

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I stumbled upon this question because of a similar problem, and your solution with strftime in the answer is correct.

Tried with your table and query and it worked for me:

```
 CREATE TABLE Entry(
       id int primary key,
       cat_id int,
       value int,
       date date
    );

    insert into entry (id, cat_id, value, date) values (1, 1, 50, '2019-03-19');
    insert into entry (id, cat_id, value, date) values (2, 1, 30, '2019-02-20');
    
    SELECT sum(value) 
    FROM Entry 
    WHERE cat_id = 1 
    AND strftime('%m', date) = strftime('%m', '2019-03-01')
    AND strftime('%Y', date) = strftime('%Y', '2019-03-01')
```

Also works with CURRENTDATE but obviously have to use current date entries.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qesLY.png)

Comment: The question doesn't ask for a SQL answer.